# Custom Row Delimiter in Azure Data Factory (ADF)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a CSV file that terminates a row with Comma and CRLF.
I set my dataset to ",\r\n" but when I ran the pipeline, it won't accept this, thinking it's multiple values in the delimiter... If I don't put the comma in the dataset row delimiter, when pipeline runs, it thinks that there's an unnamed header. Is it possible in ADF to have this  combination as a delimeter (comma + crlf) - ",\r\n"?

`FirstName,LastName,Occupation,<CRLF Char>`

`Michael,Jordan,Doctor,<CRLF Char>`

Comment: Hi @kayeesp, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: Hi @kayeesp, Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
When running the copy activity, I encountered the same problem as you.

1. Then I selcet `Line feed(\n)`as Row delimiter at Source.
   [image]
2. Add Column mapping as follows:
   [image]
3. When I run debug, the csv file was successfully copied into Azure SQL table.
   [image]
   [image]

---

I created a simple test.  Do you just want ADF to read 3 columns?

1. This is the origin csv file.

[image: kayeesp]

1. In ADF, If we use default `Row delimiter` and `Column delimiter settings`, select `First row as header`.
   [image]
2. We also can select `Edit` and enter `\r\n` at Row delimiter field.
   [image]
3. You can import schema here.
   [image]

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for your reply. If you preview the data, it's fine it doesn't prompt any error and it seems to be parsing the data correctly. But when you run the pipeline, this error appears:

`ErrorCode=DelimitedTextColumnNameNotAllowNull,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The name of column index 4 is empty. Make sure column name is properly specified in the header row.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'`

I used Azure File Storage as the source of the file and copies the data to SQL Server table.

Comment: Hi @kayeesp Can you add some details and what activities are in the pipeline?

Comment: The pipeline only contains copy data. source is a file in Azure file storage. sink is a SQL server table. I also imported the schema for the mapping.

In your example above, can you run the pipeline successfully?

Comment: Hi  @kayeesp, your  SQL server table only contains 3 columns?

Comment: Hi @kayeesp, I've updated my answer. Please review the updated part.

Comment: it worked! thank you Joseph!. appreciate your help.