# Using a custom row delimiter in Azure Data Factory Copy Activity fails

Tags: csv, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to **produce test data files using the same formatting as the source files they are supposed to mimic** (row delimiter, column delimiter, encoding, etc..). There is a process that reads files from an MS SQL database and creating files as output.

I have made a dataset with parameters that can supply the definition of the dataset at runtime. The problem I have is the following error is raised on execution:

> Copy activity doesn't support multi-char or none row delimiter.

**The parameter that is causing the error is the row delimiter**. I have tried:

- `\r\n`
- `\r`
- `\n`
- `n`
- `r`
- `r,n`
- `\r,\n`

I read this [Custom Row Delimiter in Azure Data Factory (ADF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67248188/custom-row-delimiter-in-azure-data-factory-adf) where someone says they have been able to make a likewise solution work.

I can output a file using either `r` or `n` but **there is no separation of data over lines**. I also read in another post that this is not supported but that is *hard to believe* because you can use the default option to create this particular row delimiter behavior.

Comment: I am running into a similar problem with the delimiter in the source CSV file where there are some LF LineFeeds in some of the column data but the end of the line is always CR LF. I assumed picking \R in the drop down for Carriage Return would work but it does not. Did you happen to ever figure out how to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

As per official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text) **Currently, row delimiter as empty string is only supported for mapping data flow but not Copy activity.**

[image]

Comment: I am not using an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

So, passing "\r\n" as a parameter will pass "\\r\\n" for some reason.
And you can circumvent the error by editing the source code.

There was a similar question here: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/978860/parameterization-of-row-delimiter-property-of-adf.html)

It's not the solution you're looking for, but at least it tells you how to get around the error and why you've got the error.